# pyinstaller can not work with some lib not find: is this because outlook reason?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The pyinstaller isn't working certain libaries which are not find:

```
    import win32com.client
    from datetime import datetime as dt
    from datetime import timedelta,timezone
    import pytz
    import linecache
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    from xlutils.copy import copy
    import xlwt

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

40440 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
        40812 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
        42899 WARNING: lib not found: tbb.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_tbb_thread.dll
        43411 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
        43833 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
        47844 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
        58985 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
        59357 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
        59725 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
        60262 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
        61189 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of d:\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll

Comment: Make sure you have cython and pypiwin32 installed I believe

Comment: Please include more details and attempt to produce a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. On a side note, some of my projects have LOTS of warnings like that with PyInstaller, however the executable image it builds works just fine.